# jqgrid under jquery ui tabs loading only when i give selected index of its tab

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jqgrid

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
        show: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.index == 1){
                $.get('/Account/SomeView', function (data) {
                    //alert(data);
                    $('#tabs-2').html(data);
                });

            }
        },
        selected: 0,
    });

    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">TAB 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">TAB 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">TAB 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("View"); }
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">

        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
           @{ Html.RenderPartial("View2"); }
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is when i put `selected:1` then no issues ajax data for grid loads perfectly, but when i do `selected:0 or 2` and move to tab 2 i.e index tab index 1 then i see blank no grid, although data from server is coming.

`//alert(data);` i have debugged, the data from server coming everytime when i click on the 2nd tab thats what i wanted but why the grid is not populating.

In jquery ui tab docs i have read this
`Any component that requires some dimensional computation for its initialization won't work in a hidden tab, because the tab panel itself is hidden via display: none so that any elements inside won't report their actual width and height (0 in most browsers).`

Is this something to do with my problem ? or what could be the problem ?

**Updated**: this what i get the data when i put alert(data)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('#office').jqGrid({
autowidth:false,
caption:'office Grid',
datatype:'json',
emptyrecords:'No Records Found',
gridview:true,
height:150,
pager:'#Officepager',
pgbuttons:false,
pgtext:'',
rowNum:-1,
sortname:'City',
toolbar:[true,'bottom'],
url:'/Account/GetOffice/',
editurl:'/Account/ModifyOffice/',
viewrecords:true,
width:'1160',
colModel: [
{
name:'OfficeId',
hidden:true,
label:'Id',
index:'OfficeId',
editable:true,
editrules:{edithidden:true},
editoptions:{disabled:'disabled'}
},{
name:'OfficeName',
label:'Office Name',
index:'OfficeName',
editable:true,
editrules:{required:true},
},{

name:'CompanyName',
label:'Company Name',
width:50,
index:'CompanyName',
editable:true,
edittype:'select',
editoptions:{value:getCompanyName()}
},{
name:'Address1',
hidden:true,
label:'Address 1',
index:'Address1',
editable:true,
editrules:{edithidden:true,required:true},
},{
name:'Address2',
hidden:true,
label:'Address 2',
index:'Address2',
editable:true,
editrules:{edithidden:true},
},{
name:'Address',
label:'Address',
index:'Address',
editable:false,
},{
name:'City',
label:'City',
index:'City',
editable:true,
},{
name:'State',
hidden:false,
label:'State',
index:'State',
editable:true,
editrules:{required:true},
}]

});
jQuery('#office').jqGrid('navGrid',"#Officepager",{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:false,refresh:true},{width:550,closeAfterEdit:true,beforeShowForm:function(FrmGrid_office){$('#tr_OfficId').css('display','none');},afterSubmit:processAddEdit},{width:550,beforeShowForm:function(FrmGrid_office){$('#tr_OfficId').css('display','none');},reloadAfterSubmit:true,errorTextFormat:errorHandle,afterSubmit:processAddEdit}); 
jQuery('#office').jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult:true, searchOnEnter:false});
});
</script>

<table id="office"></table><div id="Officepager"></div>
<script>
function getCompanyName() {
    var mbsCompName = $.ajax({
        url: '/Account/GetCompanyName',
        async: false
    }).responseText;
    return mbsCompName.substring(1, mbsCompName.length - 1);
}
function errorHandle(data) {
    return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>' +
        "<strong>Error:<strong></br>Status: '" + data.statusText + "'. Error code: " + data.status;

}
function processAddEdit(response, postdata) {
    var json = response.responseText;
    var result = eval("(" + json + ")");
    return [result.sc, result.msg, null];
}
</script>
```

Comment: You don't posted any code which have some relation to jqGrid, but your main problem is that jqGrid will not be displayed. It's clear that you want see the grids, but it's only the first step. When should be data loaded: at the initialization or at the selection of the tab? Should be data refreshed on tab selection?

Comment: i want to load the grid on select of tab..mainly i want the data(that is added on 1st tab), to be available on editoptions dropdown on 2nd tab, i updated my question

Answer (score 0):

call jqgrid function when html load completes.

```
 load: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.panel).delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {
            $(ui.panel).load(this.href, function(){
                $("#gridpanel").jqugrid({
                       ..................................
               })
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    }
```